# Sacar determinada información de un string

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente string:

```
2022/12/22 13:59:07 - Prueba 1<br> 2022/12/22 13:59:30 - Prueba 2<br> 2022/12/22 14:09:37 - Prueba 3<br> 2022/12/23 09:02:41 - Prueba 4<br>
```

Y requiero que el resultado quede algo parecido a esto utilizando PHP:

```
Prueba 1<br> Prueba 2<br> Prueba 3<br> Prueba 4<br>
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda por favor.

Comment: Prueba con `echo preg_replace('/[\/: 0-9]+ - /', '', $tuCadena);`

Comment: Ambas respuestas funcionan perfectamente, muchas gracias